# Alert and prevent data to save into database if the user's Email is does't exist in database

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I created a page for booking room for a university. When staff wants to book a room, he/she need to go to counter and ask admin/PIC to book the room. admin need to full fill all the details including the staff (requester) email, purpose, start time and end time. Currently, the booking cannot be done if the time clashes with another event.

When I insert the wrong staff email (the email doesn't exist at the database) and submit the form, it will give this error

"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Booking__Request__619B8048". The conflict occurred in database "madb", table "dbo.Staff", column 'Email'. "

Now how I want to alert the admin when the admin enters the wrong staff email after click button submit.

below is my PHP code

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
    $Requested_by = $_POST['Requested_by'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $timeFrom = $_POST['timeFrom'];
    $timeTo = $_POST['timeTo'];
    $Meeting_Description = $_POST['Meeting_Description'];
    $Room_ID = $_POST['Room_ID'];
    $Admin_email = $_POST['Admin_email'];
    $Remark = $_POST['Remark'];
    $Book_Status = $_POST['Book_Status'];
    $StartTime = $date." ".$timeFrom;
    $EndTime = $date." ".$timeTo;

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE NOT (StartTime > :timeTo OR EndTime < :timeFrom)";
    $query2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
    $query2->bindParam(':timeFrom',$StartTime,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query2->bindParam(':timeTo',$EndTime,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query2 -> execute();
    $results = $query2 -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    if($query2->rowCount() == 0){
    //insert data to database     

        $sql = "INSERT INTO booking(Requested_by, Book_Date, StartTime, EndTime, Meeting_Description, Room_ID, Admin_email, Remark, Book_Status) 
                VALUES(:Requested_by, GETDATE(), :StartTime, :EndTime, :Meeting_Description, :Room_ID, :Admin_email, :Remark, :Book_Status)";
        $query = $conn->prepare($sql);

        $query->bindparam(':Requested_by', $Requested_by);
        $query->bindparam(':StartTime', $StartTime);
        $query->bindparam(':EndTime', $EndTime); 
        $query->bindparam(':Meeting_Description', $Meeting_Description);
        $query->bindparam(':Room_ID', $Room_ID);
        $query->bindparam(':Admin_email', $Admin_email);
        $query->bindparam(':Remark', $Remark);
        $query->bindparam(':Book_Status', $Book_Status);
        $query->execute();

        if ($query2->rowCount() > 0){

            header("Location:../dashboard/dashboard_admin.php");

        } else {

        echo "
            <script>alert('Something wrong, please try again')</script>
            <script>window.location = '../dashboard/dashboard_admin.php'</script>
        ";
        }

    } else {

        echo "
            <script>alert('The time range you are selected is conflicted with another meeting')</script>
            <script>window.location = 'manual_booking.php'</script>
        ";

    }

}


?>
```

Comment: I would just select id from staff table where email is. If row returned, all good. If not, return error. Seems much more friendly than returning actual database errors.

Comment: @icecub can you post the answer

Comment: I cannot. I don't know the actual Staff table structure so my answer would not work. You seem to be doing fine above (though there are errors in that script) so it shouldn't be that hard to do?

Comment: Sorry, that part was actually my fault, not yours. Anyway, just do something like `SELECT id FROM Staff WHERE email = :email`. Then `$query3->bindParam(':email', $Admin_email);`. Execute. Then `if($query3->rowCount() > 0){ //Staff found } else { //error No staff }`

Comment: Foreign key cannot have a value in that column that is not also in the primary key column of the referenced table. That means email address must be there in your primary table. So either remove foreign key or first make entry in primary table and then insert in booking

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key cannot have a value in that column that is not also in the primary key column of the referenced table. That means email address must be there in your primary table. So either remove a foreign key or first make an entry in primary table and then insert in booking.